# How do I do an "OR" for my python regex?

Tags: python, regex

```
re.compile("abc")
```

I would like to do "abc" OR "xyz".

Comment: This sort of question fascinates me because the answer is clearly written in the documentation. Did you not read it, or did you just find it too hard to understand? If the latter, you might want to consider filing a bug report with some information that you think might help make the documentation more clear.

Comment: For future reference, the documentation for Python's `re` module is here: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html and an excellent introduction is at http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html

Comment: @Bryan there is no need to berate the OP. It's uncalled for. You don't like the question? Don't answer it. Joel has *repeatedly* said that just because the answer is on google or otherwise easily accessible doesn't mean you can't ask it.

Comment: @cletus: I see no berate here. @Bryan doesn't say he doesn't like the question; he's fascinated by it. He's not answering, he's commenting. He's not saying the OP can't ask it. BTW, have you checked out the OP's question-asking profile?

Comment: @cletus: I wasn't intending to berate. I was intending to encourage them to read documentation, and if they find it lacking, to contribute to making it better.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `|`:

```
re.compile("abc|xyz")
```

It's worth perusing [regular-expression.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) for detailed information as well as [Regular Expression HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html) and [re — Regular expression operations](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) from the Python documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take this opportunity to point you to an excellent reference for many of life's problems: Wikipedia.

[Regular Expressions on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

You might also find answers [here](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=regular+expressions&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=).

Answer (score 0):

I'm more a perl regex guy, but the current popular answer seems to match either abcyz or abxyz. I normally would have the regex look like "(abc)|(xyz)". You want to use the parenthesis to group the 2 strings your looking for.

Comment: `abc|xyz` is correct on Python, Perl, and pretty much any other regex flavor that has `|`.

Comment: @interjay, that may be true, but grouping makes it easier to understand.

Comment: Using bare parentheses makes it a capturing group and thus potentially slower. If you want understandability, use re.VERBOSE.

Answer (score 0):

Remember the doc property inside of python.  In particular, you can access it for regex by typing

```
import re 
re.__doc__
```

at the python shell or by using a python doc browser such as the one built into Spyder.

This particular question is addressed there.